# how can I repair a blown USB flash drive circuit?

Tags: usb, failure

*paragraphed to sooth Bimpelrekkie's brain :)*

So I was assembling an older windows PC with a socket 775 Intel motherboard. During assembly I unintentionally mounted the USB connector one pin over to the left on the USB header. After PC assembly, I turned on the machine and excitedly inserted my new 32GB USB flash drive into the front USB port with all the drivers.

*click* I waited...Oops, no there was no detection! Nothing. Hmm I figured, let me try my other 32 GB USB flash drive.

*Click* Again, nothing. Hmm let me try my LAST 16GB USB flash drive.

*click* Once again, nothing.

I started to blame the board and that perhaps by some stroke of bad luck I statically zapped my USB controller..somehow. So I took a closer look at where I mounted the USB connector..and there it was. The one pin located underneath the vacant pin slot on the header was exposed..and therefore with the shift in the mounting, negative pins became positive pins and my poor blessed USB drives, I believe, became the victim of incorrect polarities of voltage.

Once I re-inserted the USB connector back on the header properly, the new USB drives no longer worked. No power, no lights to them, nothing...no detection, no power. My last remaining and useless 6 yr old usb 2GB flash drives were read instantly because I hadn't inserted them prior to screwing up.  Unfortunately, no drivers of any use were on them.

So, now that my plight has been announced, is there any way I can undo the damage I may have inflicted upon these new flash drives and get them working again?? TIA

Comment: 1) Wall of text: use **paragraphs** to split the text in sections to make it more easily readable. Now it's so unreadable that I don't even bother reading it, it hurts my brain too much. 2) This is a repair question and therefore **Off Topic**.

Comment: Go and buy new ones...

Comment: huh? no i want my data on them. Can they not be zapped back to proper working order?

Comment: you cannot un-fry a chip : frite or usb ... Obviously you have a backup of all your data and drivers etc...

Comment: but it is your belief that this is what I did??

Comment: you have proved it - the old ones that you did not zap still work and the "new", well old and useless now, don't...

Comment: I believe you're right solar mike..i just didnt want to accept it...dam

Comment: It is usually the consequence of that sort of error - which is why some of the connectors have lumps and cutouts to help prevent that type of thing... but they don't always work...

Comment: @EyeFryed If the data is valuable enough, you could consider the idea of hiring a company to attempt a recovery of the data. This might be from moderate efforts to extreme efforts and a professional company will take the cheaper approaches first and inform you at each new stage of failure about the likely costs of the next step. It could be a chip related to, but not directly itself, the flash memory chip. So perhaps there's a cheaper chance here. But it takes people with some experience and tools.

Comment: don't try anything with them - someone else may also have an opinion on here better than mine so DON'T trash them you may be lucky but ...

Comment: @EyeFryed This makes two other points: (1) The connectors on the motherboard for USB should have been designed so that such errors aren't possible, if the motherboards are designed to be put together by end-users who aren't always going to be perfectly careful; or, (2) if the connectors remain like this, end-users need to be perfectly careful throughout the assembly process. -- I have to say that I assemble all of my own computers and I'm constantly aware of (and frightened by) my own ability to make mistakes. So I spend lots of time rechecking my work and where possible asking others, also.

Comment: @jonk could have been worse..could have lost the USB controller too..i  thought the headers were a little more fail safe than that.but apparently not. Lesson learned. Also..when working it tight spots and low light, be exceptionally more careful. And wear glasses if you need them. Had I followed this, I wouldn't be here right now.

Comment: @EyeFryed It's easy to kibbitz from 20/20 hindsight and all that. I actually have wished that at some point motherboard manufacturers had understood from the start that their motherboards would be handled by individuals building only one, or a small number of, machines. And that they would ***not*** have developed "routines" for getting things done right every single time. It's an easy fix. Use a 5-pin connector and block one pin (#2) and use a slightly wider header on the board. It would not have been expensive. And you would have been saved this grief. But there it is.

Comment: There is another lesson or two here. When working on equipment like this DO NOT PLUG IN something you are not prepared to lose. And, if the first thing you plug in does not work, it's probably something you did, not a fault of the thing you plugged in. Again 20-20 hindsight is universal, but someone else reading this might be saved the grief.

Comment: Comment stream is longer than the answer, which states that your problem is NOT repairable. Off-topic question to begin with. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

From the description of how your 2X5 connector was attached, it seems it was shifted towards the power pin. This means that one of data wires was carrying +5V, and this voltage was propagated to your pen drive. Apparently the USB interface in your pen drive was destroyed. There is no way to repair the interface. The only option to retrieve your data is to de-solder the flash chip, and recover the data in professional environment.

In the past USB Specs, the data pins were required to be tolerant to shorting them to +5V VBUS.  But later the USB-IF organisation has lifted this requirement, arguing that this condition can never happen in normal cable environment, and even a dog chewing a USB cable is very unlikely to create this condition (short D+ or D- to VBUS; a short to ground would happen more likely, turning off VBUS). They argued that in modern low-voltage silicon technology (65 nm and smaller) it is "it is not easily support 5V levels" and to provide the necessary protection, so the requirement was removed from USB 2.0 Specifications, by ECN (#15) of 2008.

Comment: thanks for that technical description. I just wish this Dell case had the hole on the connector for the vacant pin slot plugged! Then I couldn't have pushed it on..and I would have looked more closely as to why it wasn't fitting. This goes back to what jonk was saying about the designers and what was meant for end users and what wasn't. This could have easily happened to even the most experienced assembler and could have been avoided if the maker of that plug (molex?) had covered the no. 10 hole on the connector imo.